# Definition of a split reductive algebraic $\mathbb{Z}$-group in Jantzen

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups

In the beginning of Part II of Jantzen's "Representations of algebraic groups", Jantzen begins his discussion of reductive groups.

In Part II, $\S1.1$, he begins: "Let $G_\mathbb{Z}$ be a split and reductive algebraic $\mathbb{Z}$-group."

The problem is, I cannot find a definition of a split reductive algebraic group anywhere in his book (I've looked through the index, and also used Ctrl+F for "reductive"). Am I missing something, or does he really not define such a central concept? I understand this is well-discussed in the literature, but given the level of detail he goes to in his book, it seems out of place for him to omit such a basic definition, especially since he discusses such groups over general rings which are not fields, and the main body of literature focuses on the case where the base ring is a field.

Here are my guesses for the definitions (with questions) - I would appreciate any corrections as needed:

Early on in Part I $\S2.1$ he defines an algebraic group over a ring $A$ as a affine group scheme of finite presentation over $A$.

When $k$ is a field, in Part I $\S2.14$, he defines a unipotent algebraic group as an algebraic group isomorphic to a closed subgroup of the standard upper triangular unipotent group $U_{n,k}\subset GL_{n,k}$ for some $n$.

Am I to understand a unipotent algebraic group over $A$ to be a closed subgroup of $U_{n,A}\subset GL_{n,A}$ for some $n$?

Is a reductive algebraic group over $A$ an algebraic group with no nontrivial normal unipotent subgroups, and connected geometric fibers (over $A$)? Do we need to require that it is $A$-flat?

The definition of "split maximal" is a bit more ambiguous. Should I understand a split torus over $A$ to be an algebraic group isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_{m,A}^n$ (for some $n$)? Should I understand a split maximal torus of a reductive algebraic group $G$ to be a closed subgroup isomorphic to a split torus such that its geometric fibers over $A$ (for various alg. closed fields $k$) are *all* maximal inside $G_k$? (Presumably if $G$ is not $A$-flat, it could happen that some geometric fibers are maximal, but others are not?)

Comment: All of these questions are answered in Brian Conrad’s *Reductive group schemes* notes.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks for the reference! Though for me part of the question is really - "What is the consensus on what Jantzen means by a split reductive algebraic group over $A$"?, and "Is it really true that Jantzen doesn't define them?".

Comment: Hey, so for your first question my answer is: what is written in Conrad. Did you want me to reproduce it here for you? For your second question: I’m not sure—does it really matter? I am very confident that whatever Jantzen uses, or intended to use, for both split and reductive, is what is in Conrad.

Comment: By the way, rereading my previous comment it sounds hostile. That wasn’t my intention! Sorry I can’t help more.

Comment: @AlexYoucis No worries! A part of my question is also just expressing my shock at why a book on representations of algebraic groups that goes into so much detail in describing group schemes and Hopf algebras would omit the definition of reductive and split reductive. I wonder if it's an issue with the pdf - maybe Ctrl+F isn't finding everything (though I've tried others, with no better results).

Comment: Part II of Jantzen's book starts just by fixing notation for things the reader is already assumed to be familiar with - the introduction to the whole book says as much: "In part II, the reader is supposed to know the structure of reductive algebraic groups ...". There are references of where to look for proofs of the actual results. Jantzen not only omits the definition of many things here, but also takes for granted that the reader is (for example) intimately familiar with the root systems associated to reductive groups.